# Change Image on click constantly with score

Tags: javascript, html

I have my code set up so when a user clicks on the image it goes to another image and then when they click on that image it goes to another html page. I can't have 10 html pages of basically the same thing and also I need it to keep score.

```
        <img src="img/question1.png" alt="" style= "width: 15em;" id="question1"  usemap="map"/>

        <map name="map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="114,296,17,262" onclick="toggleImage()";>
            <area shape="rect" coords="140,266,234,294" onclick="right()";>

            <area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" href="quiz2.html">
```

I have this for the image mapping and hrefs

```
function toggleImage(){ 

      var img = document.getElementById("question1");
      img.src = img.src.indexOf("fact1.png")!=-1?"img/question1.png":"img/fact1.png";

}
function right(){

     var img = document.getElementById("question1");
     img.src = img.src.indexOf("fact1.png")!=-1?"img/question1.png":"img/fact1.png";

}
```

and this for the Javascript.

Everything works here I just need it to keep score mostly, but when the html page changes thats when I can't keep score.

Answer (score 3):

Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for storing data for sessions and across pages.

Store a counter across the pages, which you can then use to id the images. When changing the image to display, change the counter and store it with sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("counter", "value");
```

On page that loads after, use `onload()` event to immediately get the stored item:

```
<body onload="init()">
  <img id="question1"></img>
</body>

function init() {
  var imgCounter = sessionStorage.getItem("counter");
  var img = document.getElementById("question1");
  img.src = "fact" + imgCounter + ".png"; }
```

Comment: Your answer should go as comment.

Comment: I did some research and decided that sessionStorage would be best for what I'm doing but how do I implement that into my own code with the image mapping and functions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your score outside. You can use cookies, localstorage or a database, depending on the project itself.
If you want to use cookies, this is simple solution:

```
//set cookie
document.cookie="score=10";

//get cookie
var score = document.cookie;
```

If you need, I can help you developing your project. Just let me know

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent answers for keeping score between pages, but I also want to address the part about *"I can't have 10 html pages of basically the same thing"*

First of all, you should place the javascript in a separate file like `quiz.js`, and use the same file on every page.

```
<script src="quiz.js"></script>
```

That way you only have to write the scripts to handle the quiz in one place. This will not help you with storing score between pages, so you still need cookies, localstorage or a database as sugested in other answers.

But to go further than that, you should probably look into keeping the entire quiz in one html file. I'll give you an example below to get you started, with a working example at the bottom. Now I don't know what you quiz is about or how it is supposed to work in the end, but hopefully you will find this helpful as you move forward.

Information about each *page* is stored in `quiz = [{page1},{page2}]`, where each page contains information like page name, image and other things that are required for that page.

When you in your example move to `quiz2.html`, instead you move to the next page in the quiz array and simply redraw the page with the new information. No reloading the page, just redraw it with new information.

```js
var score = 0,
  current = null,
  quiz = [{
    name: 'quiz page 1',
    image: 'https://placekitten.com/200/203'
  }, {
    name: 'quiz page 2',
    image: 'https://placekitten.com/200/303'
  }],
  img,
  title,
  score,
  currentScore = 0;

function toggleImage() {
  currentScore++;
  updateScore();
  img.src = "https://placekitten.com/203/205";
}

function right() {
  currentScore++;
  updateScore();
  img.src = "https://placekitten.com/203/200";
}

function next() {
  var i = quiz.indexOf(current) + 1;
  if (i < quiz.length) current = quiz[i];
  show();
}

function show() {
  img.src = current.image;
  title.innerText = current.name;
  updateScore();
}

function updateScore() {
  score.innerText = currentScore;
}

window.onload = function() {
  img = document.getElementById("question");
  title = document.getElementById("title");
  score = document.getElementById("score");
  current = quiz[0];
  show()
};
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>
<div>
  Score: <span id="score"></span>
</div>
<img alt="" id="question" usemap="map" />

<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" onclick="toggleImage()" ;>
  <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,200,100" onclick="right()" ;>
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,100,200,200" onclick="next()">
</map>
```